# Optional shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I want to develop custom shipping method in Magento CE 1.9 as per following functionality:
Either `Flat Rate`(< $49) or `Free shipping`(>= $49) will be applied on order **automatically**.
There will be another shipping method for faster shipping.
Customer can select whether to choose for faster shipping or not in shipping method block.
If customer opts for faster shipping then additional amount will be added to applied shipping charge and that method will be selected.
I tried with applying minimum total for Free shipping. But user is able to choose between `Flat Rate` or `Free shipping`. Please refer image for current settings: 
[image: Current settings]

Can anyone give some pointers how I can do this?
Thanks in Advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `min_order_total` and `max_order_total`.

Just add on your two custom shipping methods in `system.xml` two options:

```
<min_order_total translate="label">
  <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
  <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
  <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</min_order_total>

<max_order_total translate="label">
  <label>Maximum Order Total</label>
  <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
  <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</max_order_total>
```

And adjust them to show the first method for order between 0 and 49$ and the second method from 49$.

Then just add another flat method always present and without order's amount restriction.

Of course you will have to turn free shipping off (if I correctly understood).